# amadeus - American Airlines

Tags: amadeus

Using self-service API in production mode - I am not getting American Airlines in the results. Example:  "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=PHX&destinationLocationCode=SFO&departureDate=2019-12-02&returnDate=2019-12-04&adults=1&travelClass=ECONOMY&nonStop=true&currencyCode=USD&max=20" will give other airlines but not AA.  Both the AA site and KAYAK show AA non-stops on those dates.
What Am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Amadeus, "Our APIs return all airline except low cost carriers and American Airline’s flights. We are currently working on this but the negotiations with the airline are still ongoing."